# how to convert unix timestamp with z to date time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

how would i convert this timestamp '20141031131429Z' to 31 october 2014 in python

```
>>>datetime.datetime.strptime( "20141031131429Z", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%Z" )
```

the above code gives me an error shown below:

```
ValueError: time data '20141031131429Z' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%Z'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `%` in front of the `Z`:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("20141031131429Z", "%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ" )
print(d.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
```

Output:

```
31 October 2014
```

Set the documentation for the [strftime() and strptime() behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: can i get it as 31 october 2014

Comment: Hey I too am getting similar error-
time data '2014-10-31T20:02:36.622Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.Z'

I am not able to figure out "T20:02:36.622Z" part, earlier it gave me error wherein I realized it wanted 5 arguments I was giving only 3.

    cDate = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ',story.CreationDate)
    date_object = datetime.strptime(cDate, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.Z')

Answer (score 0):

That's not a unix timestamp (which are parsed with %s in strftime/strptime) - it looks like [iCalendar form #2](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html) (RFC 2445). A module like [iCalendar](http://icalendar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#value-types) might help you parse that without having to hardcode which form is used.

Once you have a datetime object, it can be used to retrieve any other format:

```
>>> dt=datetime.datetime.strptime( "20141031131429Z", "%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ" )
>>> dt.strftime('%d %B %Y')
'31 October 2014'
>>> dt.strftime('%x')
'10/31/14'
```